Using ICSS in an Angular Project
Recently my goal has been trying to make the scss and the typescript part of my application communicate better, in order to minimise code repeating and hard-coding.
For example, many times in a component I have to assign a certain css variable that has a dynamic value (so that I can use it in the component style), but the only thing I can do is to copy-paste it to avoid typos between the .ts and .scss file.
Specifically I was interested in "ICSS", to easily import scss variables into my typescript code.
So I proceded by creating a test scss file that exported a variable like so:
// variables.module.scss
:export {
  dynamicCssVarName: "--dynamic-value-from-angular"
}

As I understand, being able to import scss files into an ES6 module is generally a matter of having the right loaders in the webpack config, which I have configured as shown below
(all loaders are downloaded and my angular.json is already set to allow a custom webpack configuration file):
// extra-webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                mode: 'icss'
              },
            },
          },
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};


Unfortunately before even trying to import the file in any component, I get many errors like the following, when I try to serve the application:
SassError: expected "{". 

╷ 2 │ import API from "!../../../../../../node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/injectStylesIntoStyleTag.js";

I have also tried to add the following configuration to the angular.json:
"stylePreprocessorOptions": { 
  "includePaths": [ 
    "path/to/project/src"
  ]
}

And as well this one in my custom webpack config, inside of the rule shown before:
include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/project/src')


Is there something I am not seeing or that I am doing wrong?
Also, if anyone has a better idea on how to achieve this kind of scss-ts communication, any suggestion is welcome (even involving others style preprocessors or something else like tailwind, that I know allows to define stuff inside a js config file).
Thanks!
